# How can I resolve this type class ambiguity?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Here's my minimal example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, RankNTypes #-}

import Control.Lens

class Into outer inner where
    factory :: inner -> outer
    merge :: inner -> inner -> inner

-- Given an inner item, a lens and an outer item, use factory to construct a new
-- outer around the inner if the Maybe outer is Nothing, or else use merge to combine
-- the argument inner with the one viewed through the lens inside the outer
into :: Into outer inner =>
    inner -> Lens' outer inner -> Maybe outer -> Maybe outer
inner `into` lens = Just . maybe (factory inner) (over lens (merge inner))
```

This fails to compile with the following error:

```
GHCi, version 7.6.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( foo.hs, interpreted )

foo.hs:10:62:
    Could not deduce (Into outer0 inner) arising from a use of `merge'
    from the context (Into outer inner)
      bound by the type signature for
                 into :: Into outer inner =>
                         inner -> Lens' outer inner -> Maybe outer -> Maybe outer
      at foo.hs:9:9-84
    The type variable `outer0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the second argument of `over', namely `(merge inner)'
    In the second argument of `maybe', namely
      `(over lens (merge inner))'
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely
      `maybe (factory inner) (over lens (merge inner))'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude>
```

I understand *why* this error occurs; that call to `merge` could be using a different instance of `Into` (with a different `outer` but same `inner`) than the one selected by the constraint on the whole `into` function. But I can't figure out a way to resolve it.

Things I've tried:

- Using functional dependencies to imply the `outer` from the `inner`; this got close to working (complained about needing `UndecidableInstances`), but doesn't seem quite right; ideally I'd really want to be able to have a way of pushing the same `inner` into two different `outer`s
- Using an associated type synonym to do the same thing; apart from uglifying the type signature (`outer` => `Outer inner`), I also fell over because the `outer` I'm using in an instance has more type variables (one of them phantom) than the `inner`, meaning I wasn't able to legally instantiate the associated type in an instance declaration
- Adding an explicit type signature on the use of `merge` in `into` with `ScopedTypeVariables` to tie it to the type signature for `into`; but since the type of `merge` doesn't refer to `outer` it doesn't help

Is there any way I can be explicit about using the same type class instance for `merge` as for the whole of `into`? Or any other way I can constrain the type system into needing to do that? Ideally I'd like to keep the class so my instance declarations are still this simple:

```
instance (Hashable v, Eq v) => Into (VarInfo s k v) (HashSet v) where
    -- VarInfo is just a record type with 2 fields, the second being a HashSet v
    factory = VarInfo (return ())
    merge = HashSet.intersection
```

Comment: A note: `Lens'` is polymorphic, so a function that takes it as an argument gets a rank-2 type. If you're just using `over`, you can give it a simpler, rank-1 type (which will also be more polymorphic since it'll work for `Setter`s, etc.). (Even if you're using every lens operation you can accept `ALens'` and then use `cloneLens`, or something like that.)

Comment: @shachaf Thanks; I'm very much still wrapping my head around all the stuff in the lens package. I was aware that `Lens'` was less general than it needed to be, but I *have* lenses and I know what `Lens'` means, whereas the inferred type for that parameter was incomprehensible gibberish to me at this stage (not sure what the friendly synonym for it would've been, if there was one). What's the advantage of rank-1 types?

Comment: The main advantage is that type inference for rank-2 types doesn't work very well in GHC. You end up needing to eta-expand, write explicit types where GHC would normally be able to infer them, etc. Also the type propagates to every user of your function -- you're requiring more polymorphism than necessary. (There might also be performance implications, since you need to pass explicit dictionaries unless things get inlined... I haven't checked, though.)

Comment: By the way, if you want some clarification on `lens` types and such, feel free to come to `#haskell-lens` on Freenode!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having a class method that does not mention all of the class variables is rarely a good idea (unless these class variables are uniquely determined by a functional dependency).

The solution is to make the class hierarchy more precise. Here, you can create a second class for `merge`:

```
class Mergeable a where
    merge :: a -> a -> a

class Mergeable inner => Into outer inner where
    factory :: inner -> outer
```

You might be able to use the more general `Semigroup` class rather than the ad-hoc `Mergeable` class, too, but that depends on the details of your application and the properties of `merge`.

Comment: Cheers, that seems almost obvious now. I already considered using Monoid for the merge operation, but one of my cases is set intersection and the zero for the monoid of sets under intersection would have to be the complete set for the element type. Making a Semigroup instance that contradicts Monoid wouldn't be a good idea. In another of my cases I don't think the operation is associative. This class is just internal DRY, not exposed in my interface, so I'm not too concerned if it's a little specialised.